# Can my code be made into one?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've the following code:

```
    protected Dictionary<NpInfoHelper, object> Informer;
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session.Keys.Count == 1)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.RedirectPermanent("~/Pages/Login?e=true", true);
        }
        else
        {
            Informer = (Dictionary<NpInfoHelper, object>)Session["Informer"];
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

in every backend `.cs` file of the `.aspx` file.

I think this is repetitive. Note that I'll be using `Informer` in every `.aspx.cs` file.

The above code is repeated 19 times. Can I make it just one?

Comment: Well, I can't say much about ASP.NET, but that kind of repetition implies you should either have the backend classes all derive from one class (whose OnItit does what your init does above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the comment, what you probably want is an abstract class `MyAppPage`:

```
abstract class MyAppPage : Page {
    protected Dictionary<NpInfoHelper, object> Informer;
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session.Keys.Count == 1)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Login?e=true", true);
        }
        else
        {
            Informer = (Dictionary<NpInfoHelper, object>)Session["Informer"];
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

then your other pages would extend `MyAppPage` instead of `Page`.

Finally, you'll notice I took the liberty of changes `Response.RedirectPermanent` to `Response.Redirect`. Permanent redirections return the 301 response "Moved Permanently" and signify that the current page no longer exists at this position and has been moved elsewhere. Using it to redirect someone who hasn't logged in might confuse crawlers.